# Saitek x52 In MechWarrior 4 Mercs?

Tags: mechwarrior-4-mercenaries

I have a fully working Saitek x52 joystick (not pro). I also have MechWarrior 4 Mercs. Some off buttons work but the majority of the buttons DO NOT MAP. I've tried reinstalling the game, reinstalling the drivers. The game works fine otherwise. I also tried compatibility mode.
Specs (as if it helps):
Intel Core2 Extreme (quad-core)
12GB RAM
AMD Radeon 5000 series, 1024 mb video RAM
Running on a Dell Precision m6400 laptop.
The edition of MechWarrior is the version that MekTek and MS released for free, except I used MechWarrior 4 - XC to install as no other method would work and I don't like using torrents.
Running Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, November Update.

Comment: Do you have a tool to test whether the OS sees the buttons?  It doesn't seem to be a game issue but an issue with the OS not even detecting said buttons, so the game can't map them.

Comment: The OS detects all buttons in the Properties panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after *years* I finally found an answer. There are newer drivers on the Logitech website (I guess they own it now) [here.](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/x52-space-flight-simulator-controller/downloads)
After some mucking about with keyboard key mappings, I was able to get pretty much every button I needed working. Hopefully this helps someone else at least!

Answer (score -1):

I know, super late, but I'm looking for solutions for similar problems right now. On the topic of why they don't work, I don't know, either. How many buttons are working vs. those not working? What's their index? If anything above, for example, "button 3" doesn't register, then maybe the game really does expect specific drivers to be present...

You could always try to use Xpadder or a similar solution to work around that and map keyboard keys to buttons on the controller, if the buttons really do not register ingame. I tend to do that a lot nowadays...

[image: Xpadder profile for Wing Commander Privateer]